# Cannot send the body in postman

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman

I have the following code:

```
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Object> postAccounts(
            @RequestHeader(value = "client-id", required = true) String clientId,
            @RequestHeader(value = "X-client-Global-Id", required = false) String clientGlobalID,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String authorization,
            @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) String inputContract, @RequestBody(required = true)String nameInput, @RequestBody(required = true) Boolean state) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(inputContract, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When call this method by postman give me an error.

```
trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:217)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)\r\n\tat
```

Comment: well.... what's the error?

Comment: You have too many RequestBody, a request should just have one, Its better to create an object and encapsulate the parameter inside or just use RequestParam instead of RequestBody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only can send an one RequestBody, if you want send more than one properties in the body. You must create an object

```
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Object> postAccounts(
           //Other Headers...,
            @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) ObjectWithAllFields) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(ObjectWithAllFields, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

And pls send your error trace.